# It is possible using only firefox to take a screenshot of Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Recently using the web console made a query to the DOM which then converted to an array of objects and finally pretty print as json, I wanted to share this result by capturing an image of the web console, but I did not find a native way to do it.

It is possible using only firefox to take a screenshot of Firefox Developer Tools?

This is my query

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[data-pet-type]')).map(type => Object.assign({}, type.dataset)), null, 4)
```

And here is the result I want to share, by the way, to share the image in SO, I look for an editor of images online, cut it, then download it to the hard disk and then upload it here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After investigating and thanks to the help of devtool development team members I conclude that there is no integrated mechanism in the devtools that allows this to be done. But it is possible to use the screen capture features included in the operating systems. For example in ubuntu it is possible to make three types of screenshots

1. `Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of the desktop.
2. `Alt+Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of a window.
3. `Shift+Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of an area you select. (Yes, I
   especially appreciate this one)

The best part about is that is possible to copy the screenshot directly to clipboard to easily share it in some chat forum.

To do this You can hold down Ctrl with any of the above shortcuts to copy the screenshot image to the clipboard instead of saving it.

I took this information from this [url](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html.en), You could find how to do it in your OS.

I hope this information is helpful for someone